# Get document data from Firestore and show the data into each of the form input field using Nuxt & Vuetify

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

as the title said, I want the document data from Firestore and show the data into each of the form input field using Nuxt & Vuetify.

The scenario is, for the first-time users, the user will register their information into a form and its done. For their next time login, once login, the user will see the info they had registered before from the same form, each detail on each input field.

I managed to get the documents displayed on my application but I not yet succeeded to put data separately on each of the input field.

I dont want it to be preview while they submit the form. I want it preview after they have submitted, on their next login.

[Document of the current logged-in user on the form page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKCmS.png)

How can I achieve it using Nuxt, Vuetify & Firestore?

UPDATE (2nd NOVEMBER 2021):

```
                            <v-form>
                                <v-layout>
                                    <v-row>
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6"
                                            v-for="(Name, i) in objects" :key="i">
                                            <v-text-field
                                            v-model="objects.name">{{ objects.name }}</v-text-field>
                                        </v-col>
                                        <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="6">
                                            <v-btn @click="test">Test</v-btn>
                                        </v-col>
                                        <v-col>
                                            <h1>why this one can display above cannot?</h1>
                                            <v-text-field
                                            v-model="testOne">{{ testOne }}</v-text-field>
                                        </v-col>
                                    </v-row>
                                </v-layout>
                            </v-form>
```

the script part

```
<script>
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import firestore from "@/plugins/firebasetest";

export default {
    middleware: "authentication",
    layout: 'dashboard',

    data: () => ({
        objects: [
            {
                name: 'hello',
            }
        ],
        testOne: 'hello',
    }),

    created() {
        this.readFromFirestore();
    },

    methods: {
        async readFromFirestore() {
            this.objects = []
            firestore
                .collection('test')
                .get()
                .then((querySnapShot) => {
                    querySnapShot.forEach((doc) => {
                        this.objects.push({
                            id: doc.id,
                            name: doc.data().name,    
                        })
                        console.log({ ...doc.data, id: doc.id })
                    })
                })
        },

        test() {
            var data = {
                name: this.objects.name,
            }
            firestore
            .collection('test')
                .doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
                .set(data)
                .then(() => {
                console.log({ ...doc.data, id: doc.id })
            })
        },
    },
}
</script>
```

[Vue/Nuxt - Iterating Through Firestore Collection of Documents using v-for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67711410/vue-nuxt-iterating-through-firestore-collection-of-documents-using-v-for)

I already Referred to this link which suggested by Divyani but still cant workout the solution. Not sure why

I also want to include an screenshot to further my question regarding the same issue:

[image: testing input when hardcode]

so the first input when I do

```
objects: [
            {
                name: 'hello',
            }
        ]
```

Nothing happen. but when I do this (hardcoded):

```
testOne: 'hello',
```

I can display the text input. Why I can do it?

How can I do it the same with Nuxt & Firestore?

Comment: Can You refer to this link : https://stackoverflow.com/q/67711410/15774176 Is it helpful?

Comment: Hi there! already referred to the link do it exactly same but still can't work out the solution. Ive updated my question and change the code a bit. I hope maybe it will be clear how I want to solve it.

Comment: can you  refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69821972/15774176 Is it helpful?

Comment: its the further question regarding the same question that I currently have and written by me. But thanks for the help ya :))